# how to create URL chain for IPtable

Tags: linux, networking, netfilter

I would like to create chain for Iptable which return URL and post and get from all packets.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that [netfilter/iptables](http://www.netfilter.org/) is generally aware of application-level protocols like HTTP. There is some limited protocol dissection support that is used for connection tracking in some specific protocols (e.g. FTP), but that's about it. The way I see it, you have two options:

- Redirect the packets that you want to inspect to [userspace](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libipq) where you can have a helper process that will extract the information that you need. I am not aware of any existing application that will do that, however, so you may have to write it yourself.
- Do the sane thing and just use a packet sniffer such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/), preferably with a capture filter that will only let HTTP traffic through. As a bonus, you can get a whole lot more information than just an HTTP request and a URL...

Answer (score 0):

( 3 years later but I think useful for other people too )

barebone iptables are agnostic of application protocols, but there are [iptables extensions](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html)

for example, see the extensions *string* and *u32*